# What is the difference between Shao Xing and Shao Hisng Chinese cooking wines?

Tags: chinese-cuisine

Some people say that Shao Xing and Shao Hisng are different names for the same thing yet others say Xing has added salt.

Could someone please shed some light?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shao hsing is just another romanization of mandarin Chinese (Wade Giles) for Shao xing :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Chinese_romanization_systems

Comment: I agree, different systems to romanise or use regular english letters to pronounce the Chinese sounds.  Wade-Giles uses shao hsing, while pinyin uses shao xing.  Wade-Giles is rarely used today, or since 1980, while pinyin is the PRC's homegrown version to romanise the sounds of Mandarin Chinese.